# Nginx behind a proxy: avoid auto-redirects to internal port

Tags: nginx

I have a setup in which haproxy listens on example.com:80 and proxies HTTP requests to an nginx instance listening on server 20080.

All that nginx is doing is serving static files from `/usr/share/nginx/html`.

So for example, `http://example.com/doc/` maps to `/usr/share/nginx/html/doc/`.

However, a request to `http://example.com/doc` (without trailing slash) results in a 301 redirect to `http://example.com:20080/doc/`:

```
$ curl -i http://example.com/doc
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.0.15
Date: Tue, 09 Dec 2014 15:10:44 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Location: http://example.com:20080/doc/
```

Notice that nginx has included the port 20080 in the URL. However, this is unwanted as the public facing URL of the site is `http://example.com/` so the redirect should be to `http://example.com/doc/` instead.

What would be the easiest way to go about explaining this to nginx?

**`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`**:

```
user              nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

**`/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`**:

```
server {
    listen       20080 default_server;
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    location /doc/ {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd/doc;
    }
}
```

The `nginx.conf` file is the default one in the CentOS nginx package version 1.0.15. It's an old one but I'm not in control of the CentOS or its package versions.

Comment: What is your HAProxy config?

Comment: Configure your HAProxy, or use `port_in_redirect off` directive

Comment: @AlexeyTen: that worked; please post it as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your HAProxy, or use the `port_in_redirect off;` directive.

Comment: `port_in_redirect off` did the job!